# Android Calender view color multiple dates and disable click

Tags: android, date, colors, calendar

I am making an attendance app i want to highlight multiple dates where student is absent and also make  calendar view not clickable.
only want to show calendar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question doesn't look, you have done any research.

However, you can use https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View

Pros:

1. Easily customizable. [I have used in 3-4 projects so far]
2. Fits in requirement like range picker, one-day selection (event based)
3. Lightweight library, few files/ less code. You can also strip off the unnecessary code of range picker and other if you want. As for me, the requirement was only One-day-picker

> i want to highlight multiple dates where student is absent

You can create a list of object of `EventDay` which take the `Calendar` instance. You can pass it to the `CalendarView`. It will show the different event aka absentees in your case.

> make calendar view not clickable

That's not the big deal, You can easily do that as `CalendarView` is a custom view itself.

This is my latest screenshot from one of my project. It work really well.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: this showing some errors.
first error of calenderview.setEvents(); // setEvents not found

2nd error in EventDay.java  DateUtils.setMidnight(day)  // setMidnight is not found

Comment: i added EventDay.java from 
https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/applandeo/materialcalendarview/EventDay.java

Comment: This is not the scope of this problem. Every library has some learning curve. Give some time. Understand what is going on in this library. Eventually, You will be able to get the desired result.

Comment: For each event it is creating new calendar object.
how i can pass multiple dates to single calendar objects 

        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar1.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 2);
        events.add(new EventDay(calendar1, R.drawable.lock));

        Calendar calendar2 = Calendar.getInstance();
        calendar2.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 5);
        events.add(new EventDay(calendar2, R.drawable.lock));
        calendarView.setEvents(events);

Comment: You need to pass a new instance of calendar for each event AFAIK

Comment: @ShikharJaiswal You can customize this library as per your need. Since it is an old answer. I am not sure how exactly you can disable manual selection of dates. But I am sure you can add your logic of what date you want to make selected. or refer to https://github.com/Applandeo/Material-Calendar-View/issues/126 and other similar threads related to same.

Comment: @Killer Is the library really customizable? Like for example, for adding events to the calenderview there is class named Eventday.java, which takes calender object and a drawable object as parameters to initialize. I wish it could have take a string value too so that i can also store a short descrption of the event. But when i try to edit the EventDay.java file of the library, it shows as readonly...

Comment: You can import in your project as a library and customize to as per your requirement. It might not be that flexible but you can customize it.

Comment: @Killer..can you please elaborate...I have already imported in my project via build.gradle